# OSError: cannot load library libcairo.so.2: error 0x7e. Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library

Tags: python-3.x, weasyprint

I have installed the following

**C:\MinGW**

**C:\msys**

**C:\GTK**

But python searching for the files in site packages and throwing the error as:

*OSError: cannot load library libcairo.so.2: error 0x7e. Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library*

This issue happening in installation of weasyprint packages.

Comment: I posted a correct answer, but a moderator deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

Installing GTK+ didn't work for me.
I solved this problem using [UniConverter2.0](https://sk1project.net/uc2/).
My environments is

- Python 3.7
- Windows 10 x64

1. Install [uniconvertor-2.0rc4-win64_headless.msi](https://downloads.sk1project.net/uniconvertor/2.0rc4/uniconvertor-2.0rc4-win64_headless.msi),
2. Find the "dll" sub-directory under the UniConverter installation path.(In my case, `C:\Program Files\UniConvertor-2.0rc4\dlls`)
3. Add this "dll" path to the system path.
4. Close VSCode and reopen the project.
5. Try to run your code again.
   Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with this issue Windows 10 (64-bit) with Python 3.5.1, it can be either due to duplicate libraries in other directories seen by PATH that don't work or the libraries that you installed just aren't compatible with your OS/Python bit version.

I suggest installing an older version of GTK+ (I used 3.10.4) using the links provided in the WeasyPrint documentation instead and see if the error persists. I had the issue on a newer build of GTK+. The version of GTK+ installed with MSYS2 gave the same error.

Edit: I found the post where I found the previous version of GTK that I was using but it gave an annoying warning about the cairo version being unstable:
 [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38556369/6745047).

Edit 2: To get rid of the cairo version stability warnings, I managed to get a newer version of Cairo using the GTK3-runtime-3.22.8 [(Link to git downloads as per WeasyPrint docs)](https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases)

Remember to uninstall all current GTK+ implementations first. You might get a warning saying that the version of cairo can cause issues but I haven't been able to locate a newer version of cairo that works in windows, let me know if you find one.

Answer (score 0):

Errors related to libcairo-2.dll can arise for a few different different reasons. For instance, a faulty application, libcairo-2.dll has been deleted or misplaced, corrupted by malicious software present on your PC or a damaged Windows registry.

The most commonly occurring error messages are:

- The program can't start **because libcairo-2.dll is missing from your
  computer.** Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. There
  was a problem starting libcairo-2.dll. The specified module could not
  be found. Error loading libcairo-2.dll.
- The specified module could    not be found. The code execution cannot
  proceed because    libcairo-2.dll was not found. **Reinstalling the
  program may fix this    problem.**
- libcairo-2.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it
  contains an error. Try installing the program again using the
  original installation media or contact your system administrator or
  the software vender for support.
- In the vast majority of cases, the    solution is to properly
  **reinstall libcairo-2.dll on your PC, to the    Windows system folder**.
- Alternatively, some programs, notably PC    games, require    that
  the DLL file is placed in the game/application    installation
  folder.

**Download libcairo-2.dll below to solve your dll problem.**
https://www.dll-files.com/libcairo-2.dll.html#google_vignette

next, extract file in :
**C:\Program Files**

---

Python, cairo, Pango and GDK-PixBuf **need to be installed separately.**
https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/v52.5/install.html

**pip install CPython ≥ 3.6.0**

**pip install cairo ≥ 1.15.4 1**

**pip install Pango ≥ 1.38.0 2**

**pip install setuptools ≥ 30.3.0 3**

**pip install CFFI ≥ 0.6**

**pip install html5lib ≥ 0.999999999**

**pip install cairocffi ≥ 0.9.0**

**pip install tinycss2 ≥ 1.0.0**

**pip install cssselect2 ≥ 0.1**

**pip install CairoSVG ≥ 2.4.0**

**pip install Pyphen ≥ 0.9.1**

**pip install Pillow ≥ 4.0.0**

**pip install GDK-PixBuf ≥ 2.25.0 4**

**pip install pycairo**

**pip install glib**

**pip install pyproject-toml**

**pip install python-dotenv**

**pip install PyGTK**